# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError - new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE];

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I have written a Main class in Eclipse with following code:

```
...
int []test = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
...
```

It files with the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

How much heap size is required for this? I increased eclipse size using the following but it still fails:

```
-Xms4g
-Xmx4g
```

Comment: What on _earth_ are you going to do with 2 billion integers?

Answer (score 7):

`int`s are 32bit in Java. You'd need over 8G of memory to store that array (4*(2<sup>31</sup>-1)).

Comment: They're 32 bits, but they're signed, so that array would only have 2³¹−1 elements. (But your actual answer is correct — 4 × 2³¹ bytes is 8 GB — so +1 anyway.)

Comment: Gah, got the calculation right but the pasted formula was wrong :-/ Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

1. Since you are declaring your vector of a primitive type (int) Java will try to alocate 32 bits for every postion of your vector
2. The length of you vector is really 2147483647
3. So doing some calculations:

Memory needed = 32bit x 2147483647 = 68719476704 bits = 8589934588 bytes

Memory needed = 8589934 KB

Memory needed = 8589 MB

Memory needed = 8.58 GB

So you will need around of 8 GB for run your App.